# How do you hide a calculated column from list content type in SPO?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, hidden

I have hidden many columns before using the list content type 'trick' but this is the first time I've had to try and hide a calculated column. Obviously I can easily remove it from the view, but it still shows up in the pop out when creating a new item.

Why are the radio buttons blanked out?

[image: picture of list content column radio buttons]

Comment: Do you see calculated columns on list forms? are you using OOTB list form or customized list form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not hide calculated column from content type and  calculated column will not appear in new form.

You can see calculated column value in edit form or list view which you can hide or show.

Refer the below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the little button up the top left for edit columns, which is what I needed to hide these calculated columns in the form view.